# How can we divide an equation by a function, where that function isn't guaranteed to be always non-zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have the following equation, where r(x) and y(x) are functions of x.

```
r(x)y(x) = y(x)r'(x)
```

My understanding is that we can divide both sides by `y(x)`, only if we know that `y(x) != 0` for all values of x.

If that's not necessarily the case, my understanding is we need to consider both cases. The case where `y(x) != 0` and the case where `y(x) = 0`.

In the first case, we arrive at the equation `r(x) = r'(x)`.

In the second case, where the x value makes `y(x) = 0`, we are unable to say anything about the relation of `r(x)` and `r'(x)`.

Is my understanding correct?

If it is, than is it true that the equation `r(x) = r'(x)` is false? (As it's not necessarily true for all x values).

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Yes and the solution for $r=r'$ is $A\exp(x)$ with $A$ being a constant.

Comment: "We cannot conclude that $r(x) = r'(x)$" is different than "$r(x) = r'(x)$ is false." But yeah, for example imagine $y$ is the constant function $y(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question's been basically answered already, but here's another way to look at it without dividing at all, if you're afraid of division (like I sometimes am). It is more formal in a way, but will not let you down if in doubt.

$$f(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$$ is the same as $$f(x)\Big(g(x)-g'(x)\Big)=0$$
which is true whenever (that is, it's the same as)

$$f(x)=0\;\text{or}\;g(x)=g'(x)$$

because a product is zero when either multiple is zero.

The next step in this formal approach is to see carefully where the universal quantifier is:

$$\forall x:\big(f(x)=0\;\text{or}\;g(x)=g'(x)\big)$$

For every $x$, you know that either of $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=g'(x)$ is true, but you *do not know which* of the two. And **this is the (formal) reason** you cannot say anything about $g$ at points where $f(x)=0$.

To conclude something about $g$ at some $x_0$, you need to additionally assume that the left operand of "or" is false - that is, $f(x_0)\neq0$. And note how we're reasoning here *only pointwise* - for each $x$ a different choice of the two conditions might be true. That's why @Jules talks about the different intervals in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful, solve it on intervals on which $y$ does not vanish (you'll obviously find $\lambda e^x$)

- If $y$ vanishes only on a point $x_0$ but not in the neighborhood of this point, you'll have to "glue" your solutions by studying continuity on this point (you'll eventually find that the $\lambda$ on the left and right are the same).
- If $y$ vanishes $I\neq \{x_0 \}$, you can in this case have any thing you want for $r$ on this interval, as long as it is $\mathcal{C}^1$.
- I forgot to mention it but a complicated case is when $y$ vanishes on a concentration point e.g. on $\{0,1/1,1/2,\dots,1/n,\dots\}$ you can work with continuity to show that it is not a problem (only if this set is discrete).

Comment: Thanks! To make the question more concrete: I'm studying a video on the Method of Integrating Factors for solving a linear 1st order ODE. In the video, in order to find the correct integration factor `r(x)`, the teacher does the following: he divides both sides of the equation `r(x)p(x)y(x) = r'(x)y(x)` by y(x).
I don't see him considering any case where y(x) might be 0. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Probably because $y$ does not vanish or vanishes only on a discrete set, which allows him to implicitly do the "gluing" I talked about. Be careful he might be a physicist and don't care about dividing by zero! But sometimes you can prove that $y$ does not vanish

Comment: Hmm, how can we know these assumptions about y in advance, if we're simply solving a general 1st order linear ODE?

Comment: You can't, it has to be mentioned somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If y(x) = 0 then you have a solution; dividing by y(x) will make it disappear.

So you can divide by y(x), find all solutions, and add the solutions of y(x) = 0.

Comment: However, when y(x)= 0, it's correct to say that nothing can be known about the relation of r(x) and r'(x). Right?